# Push strings from data attributes into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, push

[Original Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGyey/313/)

[Failed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGyey/318/)

I'm planning to use a bar chart plugin from [this site](http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/). How would you push the strings from each `div.get`'s data attribute into the array `arrayOfData`?

For example:

```
<div class="get" data-stats="10.3,'Jan','#222222'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="15.2,'Feb','#7D252B'"></div>
```

I want to push the strings from `data-stats` into an array like this:

```
arrayOfData = new Array(
 [10.3,'Jan','#222222'],
 [15.2,'Feb','#7D252B']
);
```

Is `push` the correct way of doing this? I can't pass the strings into the array at all in the failed example. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="exampleSimple" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; position: relative; text-align: center;"></div>

<div class="get" data-stats="10.3,'Jan','#222222'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="15.2,'Feb','#7D252B'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="13.1,'Mar','#EB9781'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="16.3,'Apr','#FFD2B5'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="14.5,'May','#4A4147'"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  var arrayOfData = [];
  $('.get').each(function(get){
   var getstats = $(this).data('stats');  
      arrayOfData.push(getstats);
   });

  $('#exampleSimple').jqbargraph({
     data: arrayOfData 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the states data by comma seprator, and you need to remove single quote from the second and third array item in order to apply color correctly

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/aGyey/325/)

```
$(function() {
    var arrayOfData = [];
    $('.get').each(function(get){
        var getstats = $(this).data('stats').split(',');

        getstats[1] = getstats[1].replace(/'/g,'');
        getstats[2] = getstats[2].replace(/'/g,'');

        arrayOfData.push(getstats);
    });

    $('#exampleSimple').jqbargraph({
        data: arrayOfData 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have an array of arrays so that you should try this:

```
arrayOfData.push(getstats.split(','));
```

your `data('stats')` is a string so you will need to extract from it. Also, remove the single quotes within the data attributes.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/aGyey/331/)**

Answer (score 1):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aGyey/329/)

You need to pass an array to `arrayOfData' , you were passing just the string before.

- 1st parameter as an integer - bar length.
- 2nd parameter as string - Month.
- 3rd parameter as string - color.

---

```
$(function () {
    var arrayOfData = new Array();
    $('.get').each(function () {
        var getstats = $(this).data('stats');
        getstats = getstats.split(',');
        getstats[0] = parseInt(getstats[0]);
        getstats[1] = getstats[1].replace(/\'/g, '');
        getstats[2] = getstats[2].replace(/\'/g, '');

        arrayOfData.push(getstats);
    });
    console.log(arrayOfData[1]);
    $('#exampleSimple').jqbargraph({
        data: arrayOfData
    });
});
```